# How to close tags automatically using htmlagility pack

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

I wonder if anyboydy knows how to close html tags automatically using `HtmlAgility Pack`?

For example, the following unorder list should be closed automatically.

```
<ul>
<li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `OptionsAutoCloseOnEnd` to `true`, since default is `false`

```
doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
```

[Check docs](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlDocument/F/OptionAutoCloseOnEnd)